# How to display payment method form and billing information form in custom page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, payment

Is it possible to display payment method in custom page with billing information form like check out page.

I want to display all payment method with billing information page. After select payment method customer can checkout from this custom page.

Comment: There is a huge difference between just displaying your payment methods as an information and creating a "second custom checkout". Basically what you are describing is bypassing the knockout.js based checkout with "normal" html, js and php. You can do that but it is so much custom work you won't get any serious help doing that here. The module you wanna create is gonna be massive.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I don't want to display the payment method but want to create second custom checkout in my custom page. User just need to select products and will enter card information or click on paypal button. Yes it is huge work and very complicated thing.

Comment: Just out of interest: Why would you want to do that? I mean, you can customize your standard checkout to the way you are describing (selecting payment method before anything else), why would you do it completely custom?

Comment: I have a requirement that while registration user will purchase membership and in last step custom will pay as per selected registration

Comment: Well that does make sense I have to say. Thanks :).